# Google Sheet Embedded Chart SeriesType not working

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a COMBO chart (Line & Area) by change the default chart type using seriesType to area as below. The problem is the seriesType option is not working, default chart type is still 'line. My question is the seriesType code syntax is it correct?

```
function generateChart()
{

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var chart = sheet.newChart()

    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)

    .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:D4"))

    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)

    .setOption('seriesType', 'area')

    .setOption('series', {1: {type: "bar"}})

    .build();

    sheet.insertChart(chart);

 }
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: No error message. The chart type defaulted to line chart，the seriesType is not taking effect.